# Como buscar todas as classes encontradas em uma árvore?

Tags: php, php-7

Imagine o **cenário** onde eu tenha a seguinte **estrutura** de **árvore**:

```
  class / conexao / conexao.php
            mvc   / modelos / PessoasModelos.php
                    visoes  / PessoasVisoes.php
                  controles / PessoasControles.php
           util   / classUtilitarios.php
```

Esse `__autoloader` ficaria assim:

function __autoload( $class ) {

```
   $DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "conexao" . $DS . $class . ".php";
   $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "mvc" . $DS  . "modelos" . $DS . $class . ".php";
   $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "mvc" . $DS  . "visoes" . $DS . $class . ".php";
   $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "mvc" . $DS  . "controles" . $DS . $class . ".php";
   $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "classUtilitarios" . $DS . $class . ".php";

foreach ( $paths as $path ) :

    if ( file_exists( $path ) ) require_once $path;

endforeach;
```

}

Ou, em **versões** mais **recentes** do **php**:

```
function autoload( $class ) {

       $DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

       $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "conexao" . $DS . $class . ".php";
       $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "mvc" . $DS  . "modelos" . $DS . $class . ".php";
       $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "mvc" . $DS  . "visoes" . $DS . $class . ".php";
       $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "mvc" . $DS  . "controles" . $DS . $class . ".php";
       $paths[] = __DIR__ . $DS  . "class" . $DS  . "classUtilitarios" . $DS . $class . ".php";

    foreach ( $paths as $path ) :

        if ( file_exists( $path ) ) require_once $path;

    endforeach;

}

spl_autoloader_register("autoload");
```

Mas isso me obrigaria a ter que criar todos os **paths** e, dependendo do sistema, posso ter vários **paths** com inúmeras **classes**.

Será que existe uma forma de não precisar disso?

Ou seja, apenas informar ao **php** que é para ele **varrer** todos os **subdiretórios** do **diretorio** `class` procurando **classes** e  carregar elas?

Algo como :

```
    foreach ( $paths as $path ) :
         if(count($path.subpath > 0 ) função recursiva...
        if ( file_exists( $path ) ) require_once $path;

    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    $pasta = "class";
    $listar = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $pasta );
    $recursivo = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $listar );

    foreach ( $recursivo as $obj ):

        if ( $obj->isFile() ) require_once $obj->getPathName();

    endforeach;


});
```